# Assembly generation failed Referenced assembly does not have a strong name

Tags: application-pages, assembly-references

I have an Application Page in which I have done coding to create a folder in `Dropbox`. I have used `DropNet`(DropNet is a .NET client library for the `Dropbox API`) for the same. But I am facing an error:

> Assembly generation failed. Referenced assembly does not have a strong name

I have installed using `Package Manager Console`. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you add your dll to the package ?
All the external dll must be added to the SharePoint package (not sur you need to safe control) in sharepoint. 
In VisualStudio => 
Open the Packadge
Click on Advanced (at the bottom)
Here add your external DLL

Answer (score 0):

The assembly must be deployed to GAC to be available for use in Application Page. It looks like it is not signed with a [strong name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(v=vs.110).aspx). As far as I know, you have to recompile assembly DLL to [sign it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41(v=vs.110).aspx).